# Общая очередь для микросервисов в RabbitMQ через EasyNEtQ

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, микросервисы

Проблема в следующем: настроил AutoSubscriber. Отправляют сообщения через Bus.PublishAsync. Сообщения по типу WebApplication1.Event.UserCreatedEvent, WebApplication1 попадают в очередь с таким же названием и объявленным префиксом. При срабатывание подписки очередь очищается.

Я же планирую создать несколько микросервисов, которые будет подписаны на событие UserCreatedEvent и не пойму как это можно реализовать из-за того что 
Во-первых в название события дописывается названия проекта (WebApplication1). То есть получатся, насколько я понимаю, что другой проект будет ожидать событие со своим названием WebApplication2.Event.UserCreatedEvent, WebApplication2. Так? Или я ошибаюсь?

Во-вторых автоподписка извлекает Exchanges из очереди насовсем. То есть получить его сможет только кто-то один, да и если я захочу заново переобработать все отправленные события, то у меня это не выйдет, потому что очередь уже будет пустая?
Подскажите как обычно реализовывают некую общую очередь, на которую могут подписаться сразу несколько независимых сервисов и которая при этом не будет очищаться.

Может есть возможность отметить сообщение как прочитанное например, а не удалять его?

Надеюсь получилось внятно объяснить свою просьбу)